# configuring requirejs reading from node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, requirejs, node-modules

I'm trying to setup a nodejs project to use requirejs.  I call my program with `node r.js ./config/main.js` and my main.js looks like the following:

```
var cs = require("coffee-script");
var requirejs = require("requirejs");

requirejs.config({
  nodeRequire: require,
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    cs: "cs",
    CoffeeScript: "CoffeeScript",
    csBuild: "csBuild",

    express: "express",
    nohm: "nohm",
    redback: "redback",
    _: "underscore",
    "connect-redis": "connect-redis",
    freebase: "freebase"
   }
});

console.log("hetet");
requirejs(["cs!./config/app"], function(app){
  console.log("closing")
});
```

and inside app.coffee:

```
define((require) ->

  express = require("express")

  RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(express)
  app = express.createServer()

  config = require('cs!./config')

  require('cs!./setup')(app, express, RedisStore)
  require('cs!./routes')(app)
  require('cs!../src/server')

  app.listen(config.server.port)
)
```

I seem to fail in main.js with the error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Calling node's require("config") failed with error: Error: Calling node's require("config") failed with error: Error: Cannot find module 'config'
```

and What I have noticed is when I comment out the line `var requirejs = require("requirejs");` (in main.js), I get further and fail at the line `RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(express)` (in app.coffee) with the error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at ./config/app.coffee:10:41
```

I have been having a lot of trouble configuring requirejs in node any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It is best to not configure requirejs to look in node_modules, since modules in that area are modules formatted for node. There is a little bit more info in the [requirejs node page](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2).

Comment: FYI, this isn't entirely true. npm is not strictly for node-only modules. There are a ton of npm installable modules that work great in the browser as-is or there is an alternatively shipped modules that is browser-ready. This module is usually specified in the `package.json` file's `browser` key.

Comment: `npm install underscore jquery` These libraries are packages in a 'cross platform' way to make them AMD-friendly (requirejs)

Comment: umd modules exist -- question is unanswered